# How do you use jQuery and data-rel to initiate CSS effects in linked element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am dynamically generating a list item in a card game (Memory Game) when a user matches two cards. The list is generated on the right of the game board and each LI element that is created after a match is given a DATA-REL which corresponds to the matching cards ID and CLASS.

Matched cards HTML:

```
<i class="card1" id="card1">
Matched card
</i>
```

Dynamically generated LI elements ending HTML:

```
<li data-rel="card1"></li>
```

I want the 'i' element with class/ID to light up when a user hovers over the data-rel LI element with the data-rel "card1".

I haven't really worked with data elements too much, and I am wondering how they work and how to make this work.

Comment: Do you have a snippet or jsfiddle of your working code? Also are you using any `css`?

Comment: I can add code, but it would just bet HTML code as I dont know how to accomplish this with JS. THe end result would really just be a 5px border of red around the item.

Comment: _"I haven't really worked with data elements too much, and I am wondering how they work"_ - a) data _attribute_, not element, and b) they "work" the same way any other attribute does, in regard to what you want - go research the term _CSS attribute selector_.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did not test the following but try something like:

```
$('[data-rel]').hover(function() {
 $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).addClass('highlighted');
}, 
function() {
 $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).removeClass('highlighted');
});
```